# Why can't my Time Traveler phase through the stalactites after the Twins' Mansion?

Tags: android, the-cave

After the Twins' Mansion, the Cave Tour continues to a set of stalactites/stalagmites. With the time traveler, apparently it is supposed to be possible to use her ability to phase forward through them. For example, [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2jRFvv-OD8) starts right off by showing exactly this. Looks trivially easy.

**However, this doesn't work for me.** I'm playing on an Android Galaxy, and when I do the same thing, the phase effects show they are trying to do that, but they fizzle and fail, and the time traveler does not move.

**Is this a glitch in this version of the game, or is there something I'm doing wrong, or need to do first to get this to work?** I notice that even with no obstacle, my time traveler's ability doesn't seem to move her - but I'm not sure if that's supposed to happen or not with no obstacle. She can't just walk through the stalactites, and I've tried it from a variety of distances.